# Does "pro rata" need a preposition?

Tags: prepositions

I see lawyer texts saying, for example
"will be distributed pro rata shares held"

Should this be "pro rata to shares held"?

Answer (score 3):

If I wanted to make this totally clear and unambiguous I would use

> ... will be distributed *pro rata* based on number of shares held.

In this sentence, *pro rata* is an adverb.

The preposition *to* that you have suggested links to the verb *distribute*.  With this verb, *to* links to the target of the distribution and typically the preposition *by* introduces the manner of the distribution.

> distribute food **by** truck **to** a Somali refugee camp

You could say

> will be distributed *pro rata* **by** shares held.

however, I want it to be clear that *by* matches the verb rather than the adverb.

Comment: I agree: I'd use *pro rata* as an adverbial phrase that you cannot have other phrases depend on. In your example, *based on* depends on the subject or is a predicate adjective, which sounds much better than *pro rata shares held*.